# State space models in dlm package - how to add a non time-varying constant?

Tags: r, state-space-models

I am trying to compare the following two models:

1. \begin{align}
   y_t &= \beta_{0,t} + \beta_{1,t} x_{t} + \epsilon_t\\
   \beta_{1, t+1} &= \beta_{1,t} + \eta_t\\
   \beta_{0, t+1} &= \beta_{0,t} + \omega_t 
   \end{align}
2. \begin{align}
   y_t &= \beta_0 + \beta_{1,t} x_{t} + \epsilon_t\\
   \beta_{1, t+1} &= \beta_{1,t} + \eta_t\\
   \end{align}

That is, I am trying to see if it really helps to also have the constant in my model to be time-varying.

However, I cannot seem to find a way to use a non-time varying coefficient ($\beta_0$ of model 2) in either the `dlm` or the `kfas` package. Can anyone tell me if there is a way to do that in either of the packages?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model 1 you could set the variance of  $\omega_t$ at zero, effectively forcing $\beta_0$ to be constant. You might experience problems with the algorithm, though.

Comment: I cannot tell you from memory,  but if you print the system matrices you will see by yourself if that is the model you are after.